# How to use a JAR file in IntelliJ after downloading?

Tags: intellij-idea, import, jar

I want to use the import javax.ide in IntelliJ, specifically exploring MetaClass and seeing what it can do. I've downloaded the JAR (198) from https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/standard_extension_ide-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/, and I know I'm supposed to somehow add it to dependencies under Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to add from the downloaded folder. The folder containing javax/ide itself is somewhat buried, but I tried adding different levels of directories and none of them worked. The actual folder doesn't even contain java files, it contains a bunch of htmls so I might just be downloading the wrong thing. Thanks for the consideration

Answer (score 0):

> I've downloaded the JAR (198) from

It is not a JAR. This is a .zip archive and it does not contain compiled classes in a form of a JAR. It has only source files.

If you are working with a JAR - you need to add such a jar file which contains the needed for your classes into the [module's dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html#57457281).

If you do not have the JAR but only have sources - you can create a separate module from these sources and then use it as a **module dependency** to the [module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) where you want to use these classes.